# How to connect two I2C sensors to the Heltec Wifi Kit (V3) ESP32 board?

Tags: esp32

I recently buied an ESP32 for my project, which is the Heltec WiFi kit V3 with the builtin OLED.
I can't understand the pinout diagram:

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osQgG.png)

Now, to what pin does the SCL and SDA corresponds? and how can I connect two SCL and SDA sensors and configuring the builtin OLED at the same time?

Edit: Thank you all for your answer. Actually, I noticed that, following this tutorial, I applied the espressif drivers and its code on my heltec. Actually, it worked but when I tried to declare the pins for the oled it doesn't work anymore. According to what @jluu wrote, I would like to change my code by setting the Heltec driver. So, to resume, if I connect two sensors with different channels on pins 41 and 42 in series, it should work correctly without declaring a personal TwoWire for different pins?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 I2C buses on the chip, however the bus used for the Oled is not connected to the pins, you have to use the second I2C bus, for this bus and for the V3 board, the I2C pins are GPIO41 (SDA) and GPIO42 (SCL)

You have to take the lastest release of the boards by heltec
File -> preferences -> Additional board manager Url ->
https://github.com/Heltec-Aaron-Lee/WiFi_Kit_series/releases/download/0.0.7/package_heltec_esp32_index.json

Then select the Heltec_wifi_Lora_32_V3 board as they have not yet corrected the macro definitions for SCA and SCL for the wifikit_V3

Full documentation on the Heltec site:
https://docs.heltec.org/en/dev_kits/esp32_arduino/quick_start.html#via-arduino-board-manager

Answer (score 0):

Multiple i2c devices are simply connected in parallel.
See:  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I²C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) for a diagram.

This comes with a but:
every I2C device has an address and you ***must not*** have two devices with the same address on the bus.

Check the device data sheet for the address.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Heltec sketch which shows how to use both I2C busses to scan for slaves: https://github.com/HelTecAutomation/Heltec_ESP32/blob/master/examples/ESP32/I2C_Scanner/I2C_Scanner.ino

I think my ESP32 kit is a later version as it has external pins for the OLED I2C, however to get it to work it is necessary to set the OLED reset as an output and take low for 50ms then back high.

```
    pinMode(RST_OLED, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(RST_OLED, LOW);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(RST_OLED, HIGH);
    Wire.begin(SDA_OLED, SCL_OLED); //Scan OLED's I2C address via I2C0
```

A

Comment: Goodmorning. Do you mean a delay of 50ms of delay on the whole OLED inside the loop should make the whole things work?

Comment: @Alice its a one time initialisation to make the reset pin healthy.  I've updated my answer my my code from setup()

Comment: Thank you. Actually, due to the deadline of my project I used a wemos d1 mini pro and It worked, with the fact that I have to use a lower frequency due to the low capacity of esp8266. I am quite sure that esp32 have a higher capacity so I Will try your solution and let you know